# Symfony/security authentication by cookie

Tags: symfony, authentication, cookies, symfony-security

I am trying to configure the security bundle of Symfony to Authenticate into my web service using a cookie. The problem is that the security bundle doesn't seem to allow authentication in another way than a form, http-basic authentication, a memory, or an LDAP component...
For the moment I tried creating a custom WebserviceUserProfiler to control how Users are loaded but when I go to the page I want to access, symfony still ask for an authentication...

Comment: Because a Cookie must be set to then be readed. Read [How to Add "Remember Me" Login Functionality](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony allow you any type of authentication; api keys, custom headers, or some more complex. See

[Api key authentication](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/api_key_authentication.html)

[Guard authentication](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/guard_authentication.html)